# Algorithm to find smallest integer by swapping a pair of digits in given integer

Tags: algorithm

Given a positive integer (**in the form of an array of digits**). We are allowed to swap one pair of digits in the given number.
We need to return the smallest possible integer that can be obtained. Note, it should be a valid integer, i.e, should not contain leading 0's.

For example:-

1. 93561 returns 13569
2. 596 returns 569
3. 10234 returns 10234
4. 120 returns 102
5. 10091 returns 10019
6. 98761111 returns 18761119

Is there an `O(n)` algorithm for this problem. I have thought of few ways for this :-

1. Find the min. digit (`minDIgit`) in the given integer (except 0) and swap it with the MSB, if `MSB != minDigit`. If `MSB==minDigit`, then find the next min. digit and swap it with the most significant but 1 digit and so on. This could be `O(n^2)` in worst case.
2. Make an `array/vector` of `std::pair` of digit and index and sort it in increasing order (according to digit values; keep lower indices first for matching digit values). Iterate through the sorted array. Swap the MSB with the first digit. If the least digit has corresponding index as MSB, then swap the MSB but 1 place with the next min digit. If the next min digit has corresponding index of MSB but 1 place, then swap the MSB but 2 place with this next min. digit and so on. This should be `O(nlog(n))`.

Can someone suggest a better algorithm.

---

**UPDATE 1:**
After thinking a bit, second algo which I proposed would work perfectly fine (probably except few corner cases, which can be handled separately). Moreover, I can sort the pair(digit, index) using **counting sort** (according to digit values), which is a stable sort in `O(n)` time. Is there a flaw in my argument?

---

**UPDATE 2:**
My 2nd algo *would* work (although with more checks for corner cases and 0's) and that too in `O(n)` time with `counting sort`. But solution given by @GaborSch is much simpler, so I won't really bother giving a proper code for my algo.

Comment: If I'm thinking about this correctly, don't you just need to swap the first digit with the smallest digit? If the first digit is the smallest, move to the second digit and so on.

Comment: @Blender This would be O(n^2) worst case because that is basically selection sort.

Comment: @Blender This is what my first algo is. And its worst case complexity would be O(n^2). I am asking for a better algorithm, if any exists; probably something in O(n).

Comment: @SrikarAppal examples added.

Comment: Is the input bounded (for example, a 32-bit integer), or some kind of arbitrary precision integer, like BigInteger?

Comment: @mbeckish Actually, integer is given in form of an array of digits. Sorry for the confusion. Edited the problem statement

Comment: Generally sorting is done in O(n*log(n)).

Comment: @GaborSch **Counting sort** has time complexity of O(n+k), k is the range of numbers; in this case, k=9. So sort can be done in O(n) time

Comment: @Shobhit If you look at my answer below, it worked for all of the inputs and it runs with O(1) memory and O(n) time.

Comment: @Shobhit in your updated algo, if you sort *by digits* first, then *by position* (within the same digit) you actually do the same as my solution, except the position check. Try your algo with `596`, and you will see why I needed that. You cannot swap `9` with `5`.

Comment: Also, I recommend to add `98761111` -> `18761119` as a testcase, most algorithms below will fail on this.

Comment: @GaborSch Mine successfully passed that test case

Comment: @GaborSch The last test case is similar to the one you proposed. It also checks whether the min. digit swapped is at the least possible significant position. Still I'll edit it with your one as it is smaller. I'll shortly go through all the answers and see which ones work.

Comment: @GaborSch My 2nd algo (with counting sort) will work for 596 as well because after sorting, sorted[0].digit=5 but sorted[0].index will correspond to MSB. So, as mentioned in the algo, I'll swap the Most significant but 1st position with the next min which is 6. Also this would have continued had 6 already been at Most significant but but 2nd position.

Comment: @Shobhit your updated solution is O(n^2) because you *Iterate through the sorted array*, then if you hit the MSB, you iterate on *your number* again, taking every digit. I recommend to add `55555555555555555555555555555555555555596` to the test cases :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As a preparation, we loop through the digits, and mark the *last* positions of the digits in an array[10] (call it `last`) (including `0`s). That is O(n).

Next, we start to iterate through digits from left to right. For each position we try to find the smallest digit whose *last* position is greater than our current position (position constraint). Also that digit must be smaller than the current digit.

If we are in the first position we start the loop on `last` from `1` (otherwise from `0`), just until the value of the current digit (not including).

If we find such a digit (concerning the position constraint), we swap (and break the loop). If we don't, we go forward to the next digit. The cost is at most O(n*9), which is O(n).

The total cost is O(n) + O(n)*O(9) = O(n).

**How does the algorithm work on the examples:**

```
93561 ->   it can swap in the first cycle

596   ->   skipping the first cycle, 
           then finds '6' because of the position constraint 
           (comparing position '1' with last[5] = 0, last[6] = 2)

10234 ->   does not find anything because of the position constraint

93218910471211292416 -> finds the last occurrence of '1' to replace '9'

98761111 -> it can swap in the first cycle
            (last[1] = 7, so it will change the last occurrence)

555555555555555555596 -> iterates until the '9', then you skip last[5]
            but finds last[6] as a good swap

120 ->      at pos 0 (1) cannot find a non-zero element less than 1, so skip
            at pos 1 (2) can find 0 on position 2, so we swap
```

Once again, here we do one iteration on the digits (for pre-parsing the data), then one iteration for finding the MSB. In the second iteration we iterate on `last`, which is constant size (at most 9).

You can further optimize the algorithm by adding keeping track of the minimum value when it is worth to start the loop on `last`, but that's an optimization already. The prevoius version contained that, check the history if you're interested :)

Comment: @AaronDufour Very good point, corrected the algorithm. Another beautiful test case we have to check :)

Comment: @GaborSch Thanks for the simple solution and also for pointing out some very sneaky test cases

Comment: @Shobhit It was my pleasure :) It was a challenging question, just look at the number of trials...

Answer (score 11):

First count each digit, store it in an array (`counts[10]`).

Going from the left, check the digits (following is the description of the loop):

Check that there's a digit in `counts` which is smaller than it. Pick the smallest one. Exception: `0` is not allowed for the very first digit.

- If there's one, swap, you're done (exit the loop!).
- Otherwise decrement the digit in `counts`, and go for the next digit.

For each digit you do O(1) work. So the whole algo is O(n).

For swapping you want to use the least significant digits (furthers to the right). You can either store these locations on the initial lookup, or just before swapping you can search for the first matching digit starting from the end.

Comment: Not only that, you are checking each digit across the entire array, which is o(n^2) worst case.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus: I only do one swap: "If there's one, swap, you're **done**". *sigh*. how did this correct answer get a downvote and 3 upvotes for a wrong comment?

Comment: @Triclops200: you surely misunderstood something, the whole thing is o(n) altogether - counts has *fixed* number of entries

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I don't think they read your answer because they think this problem is actually hard. Hint: It's not. +1

Comment: I agree that there is only 1 swap - don't know what @SlaterTyranus is referring to. However, this is not O(n) due to scanning the counts array for each int.

Comment: i take that back - it's a fixed size array +1

Comment: @AK4749 He omitted that you can just keep track of the min digit and update it when you decrement. *edit* Your comment is also true.

Comment: O(n) build counts array + O(10)=O(1) counts search for each - O(n) - digit = O(n) total. ok. just to be clear.

Comment: "If there's one, swap, you're done" - How do you know the position of the smaller digit, in order to perform the swap?

Comment: While this may indeed be an answer, it is incomplete. Elaborate on the scanning to not only clarify the swap action, but also if this is indeed O(n).

Comment: @mbeckish You swap it with the least significant instance of the smallest digit. Finding that is `O(n)`. Or heck... you could just store more information when you do your first traversal.

Comment: @roliu - "you could just store more information when you do your first traversal" - That is what FMc's solution does.  That step should probably be explicitly stated here, so all solutions can be more easily compared.

Comment: @mbeckish He didn't choose to, and doesn't need to to reach linear time complexity.

Comment: @roliu - I didn't say he needed to store extra info.  Just asked if he could explicitly flesh out his solution for future readers, so they don't have to come up with that part of the solution on their own.

Comment: I'm not really sure how the algorithm would work on the last example (93218910471211292416). I think it would replace the *first* occurrence of `1`, not the *last* occurrence.

Comment: @GaborSch: Well, it does not really "fail", its more like *I* failed to mention which digit to use. Obviously you want to use the last one. Looking that up doesn't increase the alg. complexity.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify it and also provide a resolution for each test case.

Answer (score 5):

I would iterate over the array starting on the right end. Store the digit on the right as the smallest digit and max digit and start moving left, if you hit a new smaller number, call it potential smallest. If you keep moving left and you find a smaller number, make the smaller one the potential. If you find a bigger number, make potential smaller the smallest int and store the bigger one as max digit. Every time you hit a bigger digit than your smallest one, make it the new max digit. If you hit the end, swap max digit and smallest digit. 
In python (This works and is O(n))

```py
def swap_max(digits):
    i = len(digits) - 1
    while i > 0:
        if digits[i] == 0:
            i-= 1
        else:
            break
    max_i = i
    min_i = i
    pot_i = i
    z_i   = -1
    nz_i  = i
    i = len(digits) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        if digits[i] > digits[pot_i]:
            max_i = i
            min_i = pot_i
        if digits[i] < digits[min_i] and digits[i] != 0:
            pot_i = i
        if digits[i] == 0 and z_i == -1:
            z_i = i
        if digits[i] != 0 and i > 0:
            nz_i = i
        i -= 1
    if z_i != -1 and max_i != 0 and max_i < z_i:
        min_i = z_i
        i = nz_i
        max_i = i
    elif max_i == min_i and z_i != -1:
        i = nz_i
        if i < z_i:
            min_i = z_i
            max_i = i

    v = digits[min_i]
    digits[min_i] = digits[max_i]
    digits[max_i] = v
    return digits


#TESTING THE FUNCTION
tests =   [93561,596,10234,120,10091,98761111,1001,1010,1103,120,93218910471211292416]
results = [13569,569,10234,102,10019,18761119,1001,1001,1013,102,13218910471211292496]
tests = map(list,map(str,tests))
results = map(list,map(str,results))
for i in range(len(tests)):
    res ="".join(map(str,swap_max(map(int,tests[i]))))
    print res,"".join(results[i])
    if res=="".join(results[i]):
        print "PASSED\n"
    else:
        print "FAILED\n"
```

This ended up working for all the examples. It also has the advantage of being O(1) memory usage.

Comment: "591" - Wouldn't your solution result in "519"?

Comment: @mbeckish no, it'd result in 195.

Comment: After "9" becomes "max digit", how would "5" then become "max digit", so that it can be part of the swap?

Comment: @mbeckish "every time you hit a bigger digit" should have been "every time you hit a bigger digit than your current smallest one"

Comment: Your algo would probably fail for cases in which 0 is present and no. is itself not the answer. For ex-5103. At the end of your algo, 0 would be smallestDigit and 5 would be maxDigit and result in an invalid swap of 0 with MSB. To take care of this, you probably need to also store the previousMaxDigit in addition to your MaxDigit and check if smallestDigit==0 then swap the previousMaxDigit with smallestDigit else swap maxDigit with smallestDigit.

Comment: @Shobhit Running my algorithm on that test case returns the expected 1503. Note that my code has the != 0 in the second if statement

Comment: @Triclops200 sorry for the erroneous comment. I meant for 1103.

Comment: @Shobhit My code returned 1103, however, a quick addition to my algorithm now handles 0 correctly. My answer is edited to reflect that change. It now returns the expected 1013.

Comment: Does not work for `10091`. You try to put `0` on the 2nd position, but what if there is already?

Comment: @Shobhit Now it should work for all cases. Notice it still only iterates over the entire loop once, it just offsets the counter off of the starting 0s, so still O(n) time complexity and O(1) memory complexity

Comment: Check `1100`. It leaves as-is, but should've been `1001`. Also check `1010`, the same issue (but different reason).

Comment: @Triclops200 Believe me, you cannot solve it with just one loop. Try to put all test cases into a program, and try to run your function on them, and check which one fails.

Comment: @GaborSch You were right, I don't think it is doable in one loop, however, it is doable at max 2*O(n) so, O(n) in O(1) memory. Pasted fully working code with tests

Comment: @Triclops200 You're right, for example my solution is O(n) and O(1) memory (10 is a constant value). Anyway, +1 for the trials, and for pasting the full code (although I cannot try it). BTW, which test cases are failing at the moment?

Comment: It fails for `93218910471211292416`, because it yields `13218910479211292416` instead of `13218910471211292496`. Actually it replaces a wrong `1`, somewhere in the middle, instead of the last one.

Comment: @GaborSch Fixed, I was comparing against min_i instead of pot_i for that one if statement.

Comment: @Triclops200 Looks working now, couldn't find any more test cases (I tried!) :) Good work!

Comment: @GaborSch and because I wanted to try, I moved it all back to one loop and it still passes all test cases. So it's pure O(n) time complexity again.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple `O(n)` algorithm:

```
- Record 'false' for each of ten digit values, 0 through 9
- Work through the number's digits, left-to-right
    - If the digit value is associated with 'true' go to the next digit and continue
    - Record 'true' for this digit
    - Search all the digits to the right for the right-most, smallest digit
      (except zero for the first digit in the number)
      and swap if the lowest digit found (if any) is less than the current digit
    - If swapped, report success and stop
    - If not swapped, go to the next digit and continue
- If we reach the end of the digit list, report a lack of success and stop
```

This may not appear to be O(n) on first inspection, however after realizing that the inner loop can be executed no more than ten times, it becomes evident that this is `O(n)` since `O(n - 10 + 10*n) = O(11*n - 10) = O(n)`.

Comment: More precisely, this algo is O(n-10 + 10*n) =  O(11*n-10) = O(n)

Comment: It may work if we presume that in the search you select the *rightmost* smallest digit. +1.

Comment: @GaborSch Good catch, I've updated 'last' to 'right-most' to be more clear. Also, I shamelessly stole your first comment and incorporated it into the post.

Answer (score 1):

**PseudoCode :** *O(n)*

1) Split the number into individual digits, say digit[10] (as said in another answer). Init `incPos = -1`.

2) Traverse from the right most digit , to find left most increasingPos (`incPos`).
i.e while traversing **compare k+1 element with kth element**. For, every digit[k] ≠ 0, If `digit[k] >= digit[k+1]` then mark `incPos` as `k`. Traverse till left most and find the **least incPos.**

4) If incPos == -1 return num, else traverse form incPos to n to find the `Right-Most-Minimum` digit ( as described in BLOCK below), **swap** with the Right-Most-Minimum digit and return. (surely there will be atleast 1 digit.)

> ```
> E.g  
> 93561 ->                IncPos = 0,  Right most minimum : 1 at pos 4 
> 596   ->                IncPos = 1,  Right most minimum : 6 at pos 2 
> 10234 ->                IncPos = -1, return 10234  
> 93218910471211292416 -> IncPos = 0,  Right most minimum : 1 at pos 18 
> 98761111 ->             IncPos = 0,  Right most minimum : 1 at pos 7
> ```

5) Form the number with new digits. Return number.

Comment: @Camouflage  Updated my answer. If you are free, check it.

Comment: So, with `596`, you swap positions `1` (incPos) and `0` (RMM)? the result is `956` for me...

Comment: Nice try, but fails on `10234`. Actually incPos is 0, so you return `01234`. Also think on `10010`.

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation of Karoly Horvath's algorithm

You can radix sort the array of digits in O(n).

Now we have 2 lists: sorted and actual. Actual is our original array.

Iterate over actual from left to right,

for each value,
Pop off elements from Sorted until we reach a value whose position in the original array is < position of actual[i]

If the head of the sorted list's value is < actual[i] then we swap and we're done.
else
continue.

Sorting was done in O(n) time. At most we pop off n elements of the sorted list total, and we iterate over the original list only once, so the whole algorithm should be O(n) in time and space.

Of course there's some special case checking for a swap of 0 with the leftmost element, but that doesn't affect complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Java code for the above problem satisfying all the test cases mentioned.

```
public static String smallestNumber(String num) {
    int length = num.length();
    char[] c = num.toCharArray();
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        map.put(c[i], i);
    }
    int count = 0;
    boolean flag = true;
    int ind = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        int min = c[i];
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
            if (flag) {
                if (min > c[j] && c[j] != '0') {
                    min = c[j];
                    ind = j;
                }
            } else {
                if (min > c[j]) {
                    min = c[j];
                    ind = j;
                }
            }
        }
        if (ind != -1) {
            char temp = c[i];
            int index = map.get(c[ind]);
            c[i] = c[ind];
            c[index] = temp;
            count++;
        }
        flag = false;
        if (count == 1)
            break;
    }
    return String.valueOf(c);
}
```